# 301 Redirect in htaccess from old website to new website keeping paths the same

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've merged two websites in to one. The domain that is no longer in use (oldwebsite.com) already has a 301 redirect to the new site (newwebsite.com)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.oldwebsite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^oldwebsite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm setting up redirects in my .htaccess file for newwebsite.com to direct them to the new path correctly. The path structure is very much the same with the exception of languages as the root of the site cannot be translated, only pages within /contents/

I want it so if the user has visited www.oldwebsite.com/fr/contents/blogpost/first-post for example, they will be redirected to www.newwebsite.com/fr/contents/blogpost/first-post

Does this need to be done on the old website or the new website's htaccess file?

I seem to be getting a lot of Internal Server Errors and pages redirecting to a 404 instead of where it is supposed to.

For instance if I visit www.oldwebsite.com/de/ it will take me to a 404 instead of https://www.newwebsite.com/de/contents/

This is the htaccess file on the new website (newwebsite.com)

```
#FR
RewriteRule "^/fr/(.*)$" "https://wwww.newwebsite.com/fr/contents/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
#DE
RewriteRule "^/de/(.*)$" "https://wwww.newwebsite.com/de/contents/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
#ES
RewriteRule "^/es/(.*)$" "https://wwww.newwebsite.com/es/contents/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
#IT
RewriteRule "^/it/(.*)$" "https://wwww.newwebsite.com/it/contents/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
#PT
RewriteRule "^/pt/(.*)$" "https://wwww.newwebsite.com/pt/contents/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
#LV
RewriteRule "^/lv/(.*)$" "https://wwww.newwebsite.com/lv/contents/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
#SR
RewriteRule "^/sr/(.*)$" "https://wwww.newwebsite.com/sr/contents/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
#JA
RewriteRule "^/ja/(.*)$" "https://wwww.newwebsite.com/ja/contents/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
#ZH-TW
RewriteRule "^/zh-tw/(.*)$" "https://wwww.newwebsite.com/zh/contents/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Are you still hosting both domains on the same server, pointing to the same directory? If not, why are you even checking the host name of the request with these RewriteConds? (Which make rather little sense to begin with - if you _had_ both domains still pointing to the same folder, then any request for `www.newwebsite.com` would be redirected again, based on the first condition/rule combo - because the host name is _not_ `www.oldwebsite.com`)

Comment: Both websites are on the same server. Those rewrite conditions are just what i found online when looking at how to redirect one website domain to another. I'm thinking it is best to just have the language redirections in the htaccess of the old website.